# How to create an exact copy on uiview on which transformations(rotation, scale, translation) applied through gestures?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I set the transform of the view to new view, the new view is much smaller than original one. How to create an copy of view which is zoomed and rotated?

Comment: A better format for this question is: here's code I wrote, here's what I expected it to do, here's what it did instead, here are some other things I tried that didn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Why don just copy transformations?    
copyView.transform = transformedView.transform;
```

It depends on how the view got transformed, if positioning happened trough `center` manipulation, you may want to copy `center` position as well.

If these not give the desired results, probably `frame` has manipulated as well. Best you can do is Inspect the code that transformed the original view.

May want to use [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) for that.